# Can I use @Provides without @Singleton?

Tags: guice

I'm new to Java/Guice, and the annotations are confusing me.

Everything in my module currently has the @Provides and @Singleton annotation. What I want is to have a request level instance in a back-end application (I read something about @SessionScoped or @RequestScoped but I think they're only for web applications?) where I can store some data, then the values reset at the next request. I could use a Singleton, but I'd have to manually reset the values before returning a response.

Is it necessary to use a Singleton with @Provides? If I just use the @Provides annotation without @Singleton in my module, and I use @Inject elsewhere in the application, would it always retrieve the same instance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By default new instances are created for each injection or instance request.

So you can just remove the `@Singleton` annotation and it'll work as you wish. If you require special scopes, you can use any other that Guice provides or you can create your own (but that's hard to do right).

Comment: Could you clarify? I don't want a new instance for every injection request. I want it to be an instance with request level data that I can share between classes during that request.

1. If I inject it into two other places during the request, I want them to access the same instance.

2. If I inject it into a Singleton, will it be the same instance across requests? That also seems problematic.

Comment: @strawbee Then replace `@Singleton` with `@Request`, and read the Guice documentation about it.